# How does this half bridge inverter charger charge the battery?

Tags: inverter, charger, ups, powermosfet, scr

I just can't understand how this inverter charger actually charges the battery. The charging circuit uses two SCRs on the mains side of the transformer. The same transformer is also used to step up the voltage in inverter mode. Please explain the charging mechanism of this

[image: Half bridge inverter charger]

Comment: There's a lot there to go through. How about you tell us what you do understand, with reference to the reference designators and section names. That way, we might be able to see where your intuition is breaking down, and fill in your missing bits.

Comment: Thy must have drafted this circuit during a paper shortage.

Answer (score 0):

The Lower side Mosfet is running with PWM while the uper MOSFET (High side) are tuned off.Thus the charging take place as rectifire .

Answer (score 0):

The charger is controlled by 2 SCR, probably in phase angle, and feeds a winding of the main transformer. Gates of power MOSFET´s will be inactive during the charge, the AC voltage is rectified by body diode of power MOSFET´s.
See picture: AC supply in orange, SCR gate control in green, positive to battery (central tap of main transfomer) in red, and 2 rectified windings for negative in blue.

[image]

Comment: Bravale, thanks a lot for your clear and crisp explanation. You made my day.